# code not working after moving from codepen to text editor

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to replicate an example on Codepen on my own HTML files on my computer but it isn't rendering properly. the static layout looks the same as whats being rendered in codepen, but the background with the moving squares is not working when i'm putting it on my machine and files. Here's the codepen link im trying to use/replicate:

https://codepen.io/Lewitje/pen/BNNJjo

i can get the background color to show up & the login boxes to pop up, but i was really trying to replicate it so i could get the animated background.

Here's the code on my desktop that isn't working in my browser (i tried chrome and safari both):

As you will see the moving rectangles in the background don't show up.

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:200,300);

@prim: #53e3a6;

*{
 box-sizing: border-box;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 
 font-weight: 300;
}

body{
 font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
 color: white;
 font-weight: 300;
 
 ::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit browsers */
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
   color:    white;
  font-weight: 300;
 }
 :-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
   color:    white;
   opacity:  1;
  font-weight: 300;
 }
 ::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
   color:    white;
   opacity:  1;
  font-weight: 300;
 }
 :-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
   color:    white;
  font-weight: 300;
 }
}

.wrapper{
 background: #50a3a2;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top left, #50a3a2 0%, #53e3a6 100%);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top left, #50a3a2 0%, #53e3a6 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top left, #50a3a2 0%, #53e3a6 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #50a3a2 0%, #53e3a6 100%);
 
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 400px;
 margin-top: -200px;
 overflow: hidden;
 
 &.form-success{
  .container{
   h1{
    transform: translateY(85px);
   }
  }
 }
}

.container{
 max-width: 600px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 80px 0;
 height: 400px;
 text-align: center;
 
 h1{
  font-size: 40px;
  transition-duration: 1s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-put;
  font-weight: 200;
 }
}

form{
 padding: 20px 0;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 2;
 
 input{
  display: block;
  appearance: none;
  outline: 0;
  border: 1px solid fade(white, 40%);
  background-color: fade(white, 20%);
  width: 250px;
  
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  
  color: white;
  
  transition-duration: 0.25s;
  font-weight: 300;
  
  &:hover{
   background-color: fade(white, 40%);
  }
  
  &:focus{
   background-color: white;
   width: 300px;
   
   color: @prim;
  }
 }
 
 button{
  appearance: none;
  outline: 0;
  background-color: white;
  border: 0;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  color: @prim;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 250px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition-duration: 0.25s;
  
  &:hover{
   background-color: rgb(245, 247, 249);
  }
 }
}

.bg-bubbles{
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 
 z-index: 1;
 
 li{
  position: absolute;
  list-style: none;
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: fade(white, 15%);
  bottom: -160px;
  
  -webkit-animation: square 25s infinite;
  animation:         square 25s infinite;
  
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
  
  li:nth-child(1){
   left: 10%;
  }
  
  li:nth-child(2){
   left: 20%;
   
   width: 80px;
   height: 80px;
   
   animation-delay: 2s;
   animation-duration: 17s;
  }
  
  &:nth-child(3){
   left: 25%;
   animation-delay: 4s;
  }
  
  &:nth-child(4){
   left: 40%;
   width: 60px;
   height: 60px;
   
   animation-duration: 22s;
   
   background-color: fade(white, 25%);
  }
  
  &:nth-child(5){
   left: 70%;
  }
  
  &:nth-child(6){
   left: 80%;
   width: 120px;
   height: 120px;
   
   animation-delay: 3s;
   background-color: fade(white, 20%);
  }
  
  &:nth-child(7){
   left: 32%;
   width: 160px;
   height: 160px;
   
   animation-delay: 7s;
  }
  
  &:nth-child(8){
   left: 55%;
   width: 20px;
   height: 20px;
   
   animation-delay: 15s;
   animation-duration: 40s;
  }
  
  &:nth-child(9){
   left: 25%;
   width: 10px;
   height: 10px;
   
   animation-delay: 2s;
   animation-duration: 40s;
   background-color: fade(white, 30%);
  }
  
  &:nth-child(10){
   left: 90%;
   width: 160px;
   height: 160px;
   
   animation-delay: 11s;
  }
 }
}

@-webkit-keyframes square {
  0%   { transform: translateY(0); }
  100% { transform: translateY(-700px) rotate(600deg); }
}
@keyframes square {
  0%   { transform: translateY(0); }
  100% { transform: translateY(-700px) rotate(600deg); }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="container">
  <h1>Welcome</h1>
   <link href="styles/test.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
  
  <form class="form">
   <input type="text" placeholder="Username">
   <input type="password" placeholder="Password">
   <button type="submit" id="login-button">Login</button>
  </form>
 </div>
 
 <ul class="bg-bubbles">
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
 </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to use the compiled CSS, not the LESS code.

Comment: @Gerard It works for me now - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that i was trying to use the "less" code on CodePen when replicating the example. I needed to select the tab in the upper right area of Codepen to look at the full CSS code. @Gerard was able to bring me to this solution.